# Magento: Splitting one bundled product into multiple in the cart

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

I have a specific request from my client regarding the way products are added to the cart. They are managing inventory for each product on the back end, as well as applying skus to all simple products. For one particular product (a Bikini), there is a "Top" option and a "Bottom" option that are bundled together on the front end. The top and bottom have simple products that range from XS-XL (5 products per top and 5 products per bottom). Neither of these is mandatory, so a user could potentially add just a top or just a bottom, or both. Whenever a user adds both of these to the cart, they are being combined in to one line item. What I would like to do, is separate this one bundled product into two separate bundled products: one containing the top, and one containing the bottom.

This is an extension of the following question: [Magento: Adding simple products from a bundle to separate lines in the cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915427/magento-adding-simple-products-from-a-bundle-to-separate-lines-in-the-cart)

Any help is greatly appreciated!