# How do I get the original SKU of a bundle product in the cart?

Tags: magento

I need to be able to get the parent ID of a bundled item during checkout to track. If a customer purchased a simple item through a grouped item, I can get the grouped SKU from $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest'). Is there a way to get the bundle SKU of a purchased simple item in a similar manner? info_buyRequest doesn't seem to have this info for a bundled item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Magento: Adding simple products from a bundle to separate lines in the cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915427/magento-adding-simple-products-from-a-bundle-to-separate-lines-in-the-cart/9916078#9916078)

It explains some of this.

You can also use:

```
$oParentproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($oProductItemID)->getParentId();
$vSku = $oParentproduct-.getSku();
```

found the following bit of code somewhere in one project:

```
$aBundleItems = $oOrder->getItemsCollection(array('bundle'),false);  //return only bundles
foreach($aBundleItems as $oItem):
    $oParentproduct = $oItem->getParentItem()):
endforeach;
```

hth.

Comment: Thanks. The link helps, since I didn't want to actually log the bundled SKU.